# List manipulation performance or how to make independent list copy

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation, interpolation

I have a task to solve some system of equations with NSolve and print graph of it, depends on parameters.

Something like this (maybe it is not a good example and does not always have a solution, but it just for example).

```
x+y==a
x-y==b
```

and I need to plot 3D graph of y(a,b) and x(a,b).
Let's assume that for any a and b my system has a solution. My Real system is very complicated and has some complicated functions which are calculated through NIntegrate[].

I managed to find a solution and with Table[] function generate array of all possible values in the form

```
{
{{a1,b1},{{x->x1,y->y1}}},
{{a2,b2},{{x->x2,y->y2}}}
...
}
```

or with numbers

```
{
{{0.1,0.1},{{x->1.5,y->2.5}}},
{{0.1,0.2},{{x->1.6,y->2.6}}}
...
}
```

Let's call it "myInitialSolution"
It took just 10 seconds for me.

Later I tried to convert it to another format, which is good for Interpolation function.

I converted it with Table function like this

```
xArraySolution := Table[{myInitialSolution[[i]][[1]], 
      x /. myInitialSolution[[i]][[2]][[1]][[1]]]]}, {i, 1, maxPoints*maxPoints, 1}];
```

and the same for y.
maxPoints - is how many point for x I have in initial solution.
It gave me array like this

```
{
{{a1,b1},x1},
{{a2,b2},x2}
...
}
```

or with numbers like this

```
{
{{0.1,0.1},1.5},
{{0.1,0.2},1.6}
...
}
```

It took already 20 minutes! I do not understand why just to convert array it took so long? What I did wrong?

Later to be able to plot a smooth graph I applied Interpolation function on it like this

```
xSolution[a, b] := Interpolation[xArraySolution][a, b];
```

and after this just to calculate one point like this

```
xSolution[0.15, 0.15]
```

which returns me for example

```
1.55
```

it took 10 minutes just to calculate 1 number!!!

My questions are

- why it so slow may be I am doing something wrong? Because I got all numbers in 10 seconds, and later just to rearrange them it took 20 minutes.
- Looks like each time when I use my final function xSolution[a,b] Mathematica tries to solve system from the beginning. By I already have all numbers in memory. Why it is doing so?
- Can I just copy somehow data from one array to another and make another array independent copy? Just to avoid running NSolve each time, when I need to calculate something. In my example I would like to copy data from myInitialSolution to xArraySolution completely independently. In other words it would be good to have xArraySolution as completely new in memory array. Of course if I make a copy and paste from keyboard it will work, but it is not a good solution :)

Comment: Yep, closer inspection does seem to suggest that improper use of `SetDelayed` all over the place is causing the slowdown. However, I do not see the code which makes the `xArraySolution` be generated so slowly. I can only make a wild guess, that you use `SetDelayed` in the definition of `myInitialSolution` as well, so every time you're running `xArraySolution`, you're solving the equations all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Very relevant link: [What is the difference between `:=` and `=`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487)**

**EDIT**
The most important question and the answer to it:

> Looks like each time when I use my final function xSolution[a,b] Mathematica tries to solve system from the beginning. By I already have all numbers in memory. Why it is doing so?

It is doing so, because you are using `SetDelayed` - `:=` instead of `Set` - `=`.

```
myInitialSolution := Table[{vals, NSolve[equations, {x, y}], {vals, gridofabvalues}]
```

means that every time you call `myInitialSolution` you solve the system again.

```
myInitialSolution = Table[{vals, NSolve[equations, {x, y}], {vals, gridofabvalues}]
```

means you calculate the solution once and write the result to `myInitialSolution`. Every subsequent call to `myInitialSolution` just pulls the numbers from memory.

**Remaining part of answer**

I would recommend avoiding iterative constructs and doing something like this:

```
(* define the grid of a-b values *)
grid = Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, .1, 5, .1}, {b, .1, 5, .1}], 1]

(* get the desired form directly *)
xArraySolution = 
    Map[{#, x /. First@NSolve[x + y == #[[1]] && x - y == #[[2]], {x, y}]} &, grid]

(* interpolate the data *)
f = Interpolation[xArraySolution]

(* plot the result *)
Plot3D[f[a, b], {a, .1, 5}, {b, .1, 5}]
```

> [image: Result]

However I also have a sneaking suspicion, that it is the `SetDelayed` in your definition of `xArraySolution` that is slowing stuff down. In fact, your definition of `xSolution` is also quite nasty. Because of the `SetDelayed`, when you define `xSolution` the way you do, the following happens: Mathematica calculates `xArraySolution` from scratch (because it is defined with `SetDelayed`, finds a complete interpolation of for all given values of `a` and `b`, gets an `InterpolatingFunction` and applies that to `[a,b]`. So it is as slow, as constructing your table, which, it seems, is the bottleneck in this code. Moreover, the function `xSolution` does not calculate the interpolation once and then evaluates it for different values of `[a,b]`, it recalculates the interpolation every frickin' time it wants to get an answer for a new pair of `[a,b]`. So it would be impossible to plot.

Let's start afresh and get `myInitialSolution` in the form you have.

Again:

```
grid = Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, .1, 5, .1}, {b, .1, 5, .1}], 1]
myInitialSolution = 
    Map[{#, NSolve[x + y == #[[1]] && x - y == #[[2]], {x, y}]} &, grid]
```

> `{
>   {{0.1, 0.1}, {{x -> 0.1, y -> 0.}}},
>   {{0.1, 0.2}, {{x -> 0.15, y -> -0.05}}},
>   {{0.1, 0.3}, {{x -> 0.2, y -> -0.1}}
>   ...
>   }`

Now we can do a simple transformation with `Map` again:

```
xArraySolution = 
    Map[{First@#, x /. First@Last@#} &, myInitialSolution]
```

Which returns:

> `{{{0.1, 0.1}, 0.1},
>   {{0.1, 0.2}, 0.15},
>   {{0.1, 0.3}, 0.2},
>   {{0.1, 0.4}, 0.25},
>   {{0.1, 0.5}, 0.3}...}`

Then

```
xSolution = Interpolation[xArraySolution]
Plot3D[xSolution[a, b], {a, .1, 5}, {b, .1, 5}]
```

Which gives the same plot as above.

A very quick test shows, that if in the code above I replace `myInitialSolution = ...` with `myInitialSolution := ...` even your super-simple linear example equations are now evaluating till the end of time. More precisely, the evaluation of defining `myInitialSolution` is nearly instantaneous now, however when it is used elsewhere, specifically in converting it to the suitable form for `Interpolation` everything just dies.

Comment: Yes, Problem was with SetDelayed. I found it by myself searching google, but you give me much more usefull information. Thank you very much.